# shellexecute gives correct result if i entered bad dos command

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am executing dos command and gives me expected result.

```
//executing dos command 
hInst = ShellExecute(0, "open", "cmd.exe", "/C dir > out.txt", 0, SW_HIDE);
if(int(hInst)>32)
{
    cout<<"\n Command executed.";
}

else
{  
    cout<<"\n Command not executed.";
}
```

if i executed same code for a bad command..

```
hInst = ShellExecute(0, "open", "cmd.exe", "/C abc > out.txt", 0, SW_HIDE);
if(int(hInst)>32)
{
    cout<<"\n Command executed.";
}

else
{
    cout<<"\n Command not executed.";
}
```

still it shows the command executed which is not expected.
What can i do to check whether command(abc) is valid and executed successfully

Comment: The status of the `ShellExecute` is that the running of the `cmd.exe` command succeeded.

Comment: To be more specific, the fact that `ShellExecute` succeeded means that the new process was created successfully.  It doesn't mean that it did anything useful; for all that `ShellExecute` knows, it may have crashed the instant it started up.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest thing you can do is:

```
#include <cstdlib>

// ...

int ret1 = std::system("dir > out.txt");  //  ret1 == 0
int ret2 = std::system("abc > out.txt");  //  ret2 != 0
```

but it'll show the console black window.

Using [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ei = {0};
ei.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ei.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ei.hwnd = NULL;
ei.lpVerb = NULL;
ei.lpFile = "cmd";
ei.lpParameters = "/c dir > out.txt";
ei.lpDirectory = NULL;
ei.nShow = SW_HIDE;
ei.hInstApp = NULL;

ShellExecuteEx(&ei);
WaitForSingleObject(ei.hProcess, INFINITE);

unsigned long ret;
GetExitCodeProcess(ei.hProcess, &ret);

// ret==0 ==> success ret!=0 ==> failure
```

Using [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx):

```
STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

unsigned long ret;
char cmd[255] = "cmd /c dir > out.txt";

if (CreateProcess(0,
                  cmd,  // this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string)
                  0,
                  0, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
  WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
  GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &ret);

  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}

// ret==0 ==> success ret!=0 ==> failure
```

Please consider that these are just examples to give an idea of what you could do. Real code will be similar in spirit but slightly more complex.